# Python game Neural network. How to setup inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, pygame, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am in the process of making a tank game in pygame where you move a tank around walls and shoot other tanks.

I am trying to find a way to make a neural network, probably reinforcement learning for the enemies so that the game will make decisions on which tanks should move where, if they should shoot etc by passing attributes from each object.

```
Attributes:
Enemy -> x,y,width,height,speed,health and other items  
Wall -> x,y,width,height  
Bullet -> x,y,width,height,speed  
Player -> x,y,width,height,speed,health
```

I was planning to use the keras python module to create a neural network, however I cannot find a way to set it up so that the input data is the correct shape and size as there will be a variable number of walls and bullets.

What I would like to do :

```
action = Network.predict(state)
```

where
    `state = (Enemy, Player, Tuple_of_Wall_Data, Tuple_of_Bullet_Data)`

and action is an option on where the enemy should move in the form
`action = (Direction,Should_Shoot)`

TLDR
My question is , how would I set up a Neural network input layer so it can take (1 enemy , 1 player , multiple walls, multiple bullets) and train the neural network to give the enemy a direction and if it should fire using reinforcement learning ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Overall a good question, I am just going to recommend the title be edited to make it more specific.

Comment: Thank you. Edited.

Comment: The problem you are presenting is really more complex than "just use a neural network". The biggest challenge is to create the "right" represententation for your data as a basis for a (supervised?) neural network. Answering your question probably goes far beyond a simple answer on this site. I suggest some introductionary reading on [designing game IA](https://www.raywenderlich.com/24824/introduction-to-ai-programming-for-games) [on NN's and gaming](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-10-neural-networks/) and [specifically on reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf).

Comment: And [more (really) excellent stuff here](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-3-deep-learning-and-convolutional-neural-networks-f40359318721).

Comment: What I am actually looking for is a way to create the input layer to fit with my inputs, I only know how create a grid of variable size such as an array of 30x30. I would like to have inputs of a tuple outlined in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three typical ways of representing the game state for an AI agent:

1. internal game state, pretty much what you are proposing - list of objects in the game, with their raw attributes. If one wants to use ML for that you need an architecture which deals with varied sizes, thus probably you end up with recurrent neural networks, processing objects one by one. Note, that this is probably **highly suboptimal** representation. In particular as a human you do not get a game state like this, you do not get a stream of objects.
2. Global map view. if the game has small enough map, it can be whole feeded in as an input to the agent, one ends up with fully observable problem, and data of form W x H x K, where W ,H is width and height of the map, and K is number of objects types (thus you get one-hot encoding of each object)
3. Agent's "vision", which is probably the most popular one in modern RL, where agent is presented again with W x H x K, but now W and H is size of its vision (which moves with the agent).